# How to use a variable name in place of string in following scenario?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

My code is as follows:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"pdf_practice_sheet_90_with_header_8.pdf\"");
```

Now here instead of hard coded name value i.e. **pdf_practice_sheet_90_with_header_8.pdf** I wan t o use a dynamic value from one of my variable in following manner:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\".$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'].".pdf\"");
```

But I'm getting an error as follows:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in pdf_practice_sheet.php on line 91
Errors parsing pdf_practice_sheet.php
```

Actually I want to use the file name as a value of variable `$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name']` and concatenate that name with .pdf extention but I'm not able to get it correctly. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure how to concatenate strings and variables is written in the php manual

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like so:

```
$filename = $practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'];
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . ".pdf\"");
```

Also, since the filename could be anything, I would recommend **escaping**:

```
$filename = $practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'] . ".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".urlencode($filename)."\"");
```

I believe `urlencode` is the correct escaping to use but don't pin me on that.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote after `filename=\"`.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'].".pdf\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'].".pdf\"");
```

You forgot to include the non-escaped quotation mark after the `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name']}.pdf\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$practice_sheet_details['practice_sheet_name'].".pdf");
```